# How to access the authentication code appended to URI query parameters after logging in with WKWebView?

Tags: swift, authentication, wkwebview

Trying to authenticate using Teamwork API login flow [link](https://apidocs.teamwork.com/docs/teamwork/99aa10e94733d-app-login-flow-for-teamwork)

I've loaded my WKWebView and am able to sign in which takes me to the login successful page, now I am trying to get the authentication code in the response in order to authenticate the app. Step 3 in the instructions says there should be a 'code' query parameter appended to the URI on successful login. I'm not sure what that means. Can anyone help me find the code from the response? I've tried using `decidePolicyFor` WKWebView delegate methods to grab the query parameters but can't see a code. Thank you for any help.

Code so far:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

let webView = WKWebView()

override func loadView() {
    self.view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let urlString = "https://www.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?redirect_uri=redacted&client_id=redacted"
    
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

}



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession) instead? It provides the necessary callback after redirect completion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).